# How do I import a C function into Python?

Tags: windows-10, ctypes, python-3.10

I have read various other posts on SO, but no matter what I do I get the same error. Here is what I have done:

Relevant section of .c file:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double function(...){...}
```

I compiled the file with the following commands:

```
gcc -c mochamath.c
gcc -shared -o mochamath.dll mochamath.o -Wl,--out-implib,libmochamath.dll.a
```

I have seen some posts saying I need to use the option `-mno-cygwin`, but when I do that it gives

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mno-cygwin’; did you mean ‘-mno-clwb’?
```

Compiling without that option, however, seems to work fine.

Here is the python file I am using to test loading the dll:

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
from ctypes import cdll
mochamath = cdll.LoadLibrary(f"mochamath.dll")
```

Other posts have also suggested using CDLL instead of cdll.LoadLibrary, but I get the same error either way:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'mochamath.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I have tried various combinations of directory structures, path formatting, etc, but I get the same error no matter what. I must be missing something very basic here, but it is not obvious to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your *OS*, build chain, ...?

Comment: @CristiFati OS: Windows 10. Not sure what you mean by build chain.

Comment: You're using *GCC*. That's not *Win* specific, so you must be using some *Nix* emulator. Also check https://www.dependencywalker.com.